# The "continuous tense". How can I use this tense with "better than anyone could"?

Tags: tenses, gerunds, continuous-aspect

I'm not sure what tense this is, but it's for a presentation. It's the best I could come up with while translating it into English.

> 1. Meeting deadlines.
> 2. Working with *bla*... *bla*...
> 3. Building 3 SCRUM teams of 8 individuals/team and having them operational
>      in 2 months at the customer’s quarters within a budget lower than anyone else **being able** to provide for a similar experience and technology.

I'm not sure which one of these is correct.

> Better than anyone could provide?
>    Better than anyone was able to provide?

Comment: If my presentation, I'd shorten the bullet to "Building 3 SCRUM teams of 8' and say the rest orally. The fact that the slide says less and you explain more adds richness, and it gives the audience a reason to listen to you rather than real all that detail.

Comment: yes, but the presentation is sent to clients as a powerpoint online, rarely is it used with live speech.The answer also interests me gramatically, as I've encountered this problem before.

Comment: I cont see a verb in 'better than anyone could' (from your wuestion's title) that you can change to the continuous tense. I also don't see that phrase or any 'continuous tense' thereof in any of your 3 numbered suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct (besides your typo), but I'd argue that the implications are very different.

When you say "could provide", it could imply that you or your team is the only one *capable* of providing this service, while "was able to provide" is a weaker statement, implying that others simply weren't available to do it or had some reason not to.

Depending on your situation and what impression you're trying to give, either could be correct or appropriate.

Comment: I feel the presentation is built with the feeling of generality "meeting", "working with" , "building". If I insert at some point a past tense - "was able to provide" - I feel it's not right. 

My final questions are : 1. is the phrasing "lower than anyone else being able to provide" correct?
2.I want to convey a strong feeling, like you said "could provide" conveys.

Also, if you have a different, better sounding formulation, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: The phrasing "within a budget lower than anyone else being able to provide" is too long and says no more than a simpler "**at lowest cost**."